# Auto Load next Post like qz.com

Tags: nodes, 8, ajax

How the functionality of auto loading the next post when you reach the end of a content is reached. 
This functionality is seen in [Quartz](http://qz.com) which is built on Wordpress. Most probably they are using the [Auto Load Next Post](https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-load-next-post/) plugin.

Is there any module or a way by which this can be replicated in Drupal (Drupal 8 if possible)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go a site builder approach, one solution here is [Views Infinite Scroll](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll).

> Views infinite scroll allows you to load and display pages of any view
>   inline, using AJAX (this has been called infinite scrolling, load
>   more, autopaging, endless pages and more). The pager can be triggered
>   with the press of a button or automatically as the user scrolls to the
>   bottom of the view's content.

The caveat with this approach is you'd need to rely on a Views page configured with an *Infinite Scroll* pager set with the **Automatically Load Content** option. In other words, a static URL showing paged full content. That's pretty close to the functionality, but not perfect replication.

Comment: yes, this is close approach. Only concern will be, the title of the page won't change.

Comment: did u find a solution